# request.data is empty in django REST API Request for PATCH request from Safari using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, safari

I send a patch request via web browser (chrome/safari) to Django Rest framework. 
When I tried to access data `request.data`values from Django backend when the API (https://test.mysite.com/cart/) is triggered via Google Chrome, I can read the data. But when the same PATCH request triggered from safari browser does not give me the request.data (show as empty)

JS to call the cart API:

```
    var order = {};
    order.num_cases = 8;

    var absloutePatchURL = '/cart/'+order.cartID;
    window.console.log('Update cart absolute URL:',absloutePatchURL);
    $http.patch(absloutePatchURL,order, {data:JSON}). success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.console.log("Your cart is updated successfully");                
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        toastr.error('Sorry, unable to update your item to the cart. Please try later.');
    });
```

Request Details:

```
URL: https://test.mysite.com/cart/
Request Type: PATCH
Request Data: {"num_cases":6}
```

While accessing data requested via PDB on the request object on Django.

Django Code to Access:

```
class CartViewSet(CartMixin, ModelViewSet):

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()

        logger.debug("Request Data: {0}".format(request.data))

        return ModelViewSet.update(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> Django console log when requested from Chrome:

```
-> return ModelViewSet.update(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
(Pdb) 
(Pdb) request.data
<QueryDict: {u'{"num_cases":8}': [u'']}>
```

> Django console log when requested from SAFARI:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
(Pdb) request.data
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Comment: Also you need to show the code on how you are triggering this action. Browsers don't send PATCH natively, so you must have some custom code.

Comment: Have updated the details with more code snapshot additions. Please help me with your thoughts.

Comment: @Alasdair - I have updated the code

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I have posted snippets of the codes in the original SO post

Comment: Did you managed to fix this? I'm having the same problem but with a http.put

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the content type as `application/json`. It looks as if rest framework is treating it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.